# Select all binary neighbors of decimal number that differ in exactly n digits

Tags: r

Let's say I have a number in decimal format: `5`

its binary version is: `00101`

I would like to write a function that takes the decimal number `x`

and returns all other decimal numbers that have an `n` digit difference (in their binary forms) from the original one:

so for the example above, if `n` is `2` then I'm looking for all neighbors of `00101` that differ in exactly `n=2` digits.

And then I want to get the decimals corresponding to those binary neighbors.

Is this possible to do?

To get one digit neighbors I can use:

```
bin_neighs = function(x, n) bitwXor(x, (2 ^ (0:(n - 1))))
```

My question is: how can I generalize this from one digit neighbors to n digit neighbors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generalize this by finding all bitmasks with the desired length and number of digits set and then performing a bitwise xor:

```
bin_neighs <- function(x, nf, n) {
  bitwXor(x, colSums(combn(2^(0:(n-1)), nf)))
}
bin_neighs(5, 2, 5)
# [1]  6  0 12 20  3 15 23  9 17 29
```

We can confirm this is correct using the binary expansion of x=5 out to n=5 digits: 00101. Flipping nf=2 digits yields the following possibilities:

```
00110 = 6  # Flip 4 and 5
00000 = 0  # Flip 3 and 5
01100 = 12 # Flip 2 and 5
10100 = 20 # Flip 1 and 5
00011 = 3  # Flip 3 and 4
01111 = 15 # Flip 2 and 4
10111 = 23 # Flip 1 and 4
01001 = 9  # Flip 2 and 3
10001 = 17 # Flip 1 and 3
11101 = 29 # Flip 1 and 2
```

This should also work efficiently for slightly larger inputs. For instance, it can flip 9 out of 15 bits in under 10 milliseconds:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(bin_neighs(1,9,15))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  bin_neighs(1, 9, 15) 7.472961 8.023485 8.848333 8.237502 8.594779 33.61931   100
```